# Is there a way to differentiate between a null value and the absence of a key?

Tags: json, object, null, key, jq

If I execute

```
echo '{"foo": "bar", "baz": null}' | jq '.baz'
```

I receive `null` as result.

But if I execute

```
echo '{"foo": "bar", "baz": null}' | jq '.hello'
```

I also receive `null` as result.

In the first case, the value is `null`, in the second it does not exist (can't be resolved). Is there any way to tell the two cases apart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The [`has`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#has(key)) built-in returns a boolean value representing whether its argument exists in its input as a key (or index, if the input is an array).

```
$ echo '{"foo": null}' | jq 'has("foo")'
true
$ echo '{"foo": null}' | jq 'has("bar")'
false
$ echo '[null]' | jq 'has(0)'
true
$ echo '[null]' | jq 'has(1)'
false
```